# Mysql - Query to show a single record of two linked tables whose condition is only in one of them

Tags: mysql, sql, record

I have two tables linked by the id_factura field.

The 'factura' table generates an id for each sale that is made, can contain several products of the sale table, and also has a field called num_factura with the invoice number.

The 'venta' table has products with 'nuevo' or 'usado' status, among others.
There are several queries already made in these two tables. These tables have other fields such as the registration date ...

Table factura

```
+---------------+-------------+
|   id_factura  | num_factura |   
+---------------+-------------+
|       1       |      1      |
|       2       |      2      |
|       3       |      1      |
|       4       |      2      |
|       5       |      3      |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Tabla venta

```
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|   id_venta    |   estado    | id_factura  |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|       1       |    usado    |     1       |
|       2       |    usado    |     2       |
|       3       |    nuevo    |     1       |
|       4       |    nuevo    |     2       |
|       5       |    nuevo    |     3       |    
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The question I want to ask is that, indicating the status of the sale-purchase table, return the last invoice number and then I add 1 to the new record.

But the problem I am having is that when doing the where estado = 'usado' it does not affect me since I take the largest invoice number regardless of the condition.

```
SELECT num_factura
FROM factura f
LEFT JOIN venta v ON v.id_factura = f.id_factura
WHERE estado = 'usado'
GROUP BY num_factura
ORDER BY num_factura DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I get the following result

```
+---------------+-------------+
|  num_factura  |  id_factura |   
+---------------+-------------+
|       3       |      5      |
+---------------+-------------+
```

I want this result, because this result is last from estado = 'usado'

```
+---------------+-------------+
|  num_factura  |  id_factura |
+---------------+-------------+
|       2       |      2      |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `GROUP BY` without aggregation?  Look up how to use `GROUP BY ` properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`, because left join is considering all the rows from `factura` table, irrespective of the fact that `estado` in `venta` table is `usado` or not.

Also, you can simply use `MAX()` instead without any `GROUP BY` to get the highest `num_factura`

```sql
SELECT MAX(f.num_factura) AS num_factura
FROM factura f
JOIN venta v ON v.id_factura = f.id_factura  -- changed to INNER JOIN
WHERE v.estado = 'usado';
```

**Result**

```
| num_factura |
| ----------- |
| 2           |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g5S8ETkcAByoVoiyrs8krd/0)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join between factura and the subquery for max factura related  to usado

```
select  f.id_factura, t.num_facture
from  factura f
inner join  (
  SELECT MAX(f.num_factura)  num_factura
  FROM factura f
  JOIN venta v ON v.id_factura = f.id_factura 
    AND  v.estado = 'usado';
) t  on t.num_factura = f.num_factura
```